# Vertical stretching for ListViewItems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a List view with many ListViewItems, but each ListViewItem could have one or more lines of text.

All i need is force each ListViewItem to stretch vertically as its own content.

Is it posible with ListView ?

There is another control allow me to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MVVM and DataTemplates to produce the ListViewItems dynamically they are doing this by default. This is an quick example of this.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding text}" />
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding strings}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

MainViewModel & ListItemViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public List<ListItemViewModel> items { get; set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        List<ListItemViewModel> things = new List<ListItemViewModel>();
        List<string> temp = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            temp.Add(i + "");
            things.Add(new ListItemViewModel()
            {
                text = "item"+i,
                strings = temp.ToList<string>()
            });

        }
        items = things;
    }
}

public class ListItemViewModel
{
    public String text { get; set; }
    public List<string> strings { get; set; }

}
```

As stated below in the comments, this is a very quickly thrown together demo and the ViewModels do not contain any of the INotifyPropertyChanged events. The UI will not automatically reflect changes in the ViewModel because of this.

Comment: This is a good answer, including the code, but it's very much preferred if you put the code in the answer. Then it's right there where people can read it.

Comment: Actually it would be a better answer with four space indenting, and a mention that a view model without any notifications is suitable only for a quickie demo. Which this is -- but it's good to spell that out.

Comment: I will modify the answer to incorporate this, I rather improve the community than be lazy.